# How to reference a child component from the parent in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out the Vue-way of referencing children from the parent handler.

Parent

```js
<div>
<MyDropDown ref="dd0" @dd-global-click="ddClicked"></MyDropDown>
<MyDropDown ref="dd1" @dd-global-click="ddClicked"></MyDropDown>
<MyDropDown ref="dd2" @dd-global-click="ddClicked"></MyDropDown>
</div>

export default {
   methods: {
     ddClicked: function(id) {
          console.log("I need to have MyDropDown id here")
     }
   }
}
```

Child

```
<template>
<h1>dropdown</h1>
<Button @click="bclick"></Button>
</template>

export default {
   methods: {
      bclick: function() {
            this.$emit('dd-global-click')
      }
   }
}
```

In the parent component I need to see which dropdown was clicked.

What I've tried so far

1. I tried to set "ref" attribute in the parent. But I can't refer to this prop within the child component. Is there a way to do it? There is nothing like this.ref or this.$ref property.
2. I tried to use $event.targetElement in the parent, but it looks like I'm mixing Real DOM and Vue Components together. $event.targetElement is a DOM like . So in the parent I have to go over the tree until I find my dropdown. It is ugly I guess.
3. I set an additional :id property for the dropdown making it the copy of the 'ref' property. In the blick and I called this.$emit('dd-global-click', this.id). Later in the parent I check this.$refs[id]. I kind of works, but I'm not really content with it, because I have to mirror attributes.
4. Using the _uid property didn't work out either. On top of that, I think, that since it starts with an underscore it is not a recommended way to go.

It seems like a very basic task, so there must be a simplier way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't know in vue, but with standard javascript events bubble up. Listen to the event on the parent, and check the `event.target` value. This will be the "lowest" element clicked on(an `<a>` most likely. From there find the closest parent(in jquery it's `$(e.target).closest('li')` or whatever you use for your menu.) and your parent knows what was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If this custom dropdown element is the top level one (the root element) in the component, you could access the native DOM attributes (like `id`, `class`, etc) via [`this.$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el), once it's `mounted`.

```js
Vue.component('MyDropdown', {
  template: '#my-dropdown',
  props: {
    items: Array
  },
  methods: {
    changed() {
      this.$emit('dd-global-click', this.$el.id);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { 
        id: 'dropdown-1', 
        options: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] 
      },
      { 
        id: 'dropdown-2', 
        options: ['jkl', 'lmn', 'opq'] 
      },
      { 
        id: 'dropdown-3', 
        options: ['rst', 'uvw', 'xyz'] 
      }
    ]
  }),
  
  methods: {
    ddClicked(id) {
      console.log(`Clicked ID: ${id}`);
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-dropdown 
    v-for="item of items" :key="item.id"
    :id="item.id"
    :items="item.options"
    @dd-global-click="ddClicked">
  </my-dropdown>
</div>

<script id="my-dropdown" type="text/x-template">
  <select @input="changed">
    <option v-for="item of items" :key="item" :value="item">
      {{item}}
    </option>
  </select>
</script>
```